# Moving or Copying files that are on a list (*.txt or *.csv)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Totally new at coding (started 2-3 weeks ago), and I'm in desperate need for help...

I'm trying to move certain files (*.tif files) in a directory (let's say `dir1`) to another directory (`dir2`) if the they are on a list. In my case let's call this list `duplicates.csv`.

**Edit**: this is what duplicates.csv looks like to give an idea. Since I'm not allowed to embed yet, here's the link: [image of duplicates.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD6Xn.png)

So now I'm loading my duplicates list:

```
import os
import pandas as 
import shutil 

# Load the list from CSV
duplicates = pd.read_csv(r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\duplicates.csv', usecols=[1])
# Convert to pandas dataframe to list
duplicates = df_duplicates.values.tolist()

# These are the directories: 
dir1 = r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\TEMP2' # All the files are here
dir2 = r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\TEMP3' # Move to here IF it matches the `duplicates` list (aka: duplicates.csv)
```

And when I try to move the files,

```
# Move the files to a different directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir1, topdown=True):
    for i in files:
        if i in duplicates:
            shutil.move((os.path.join(root, i)), dir2)
```

For some reason I can't get this to work.

**Edit**: It didn't give an error message, but the duplicate files aren't moved to `dir2`

Any assistance for this rookie is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information about what happens than "For some reason I can't get this to work". Do you get an error message? What final state does the file system end up in?

Comment: What is `df_duplicates`? Is that supposed to be the variable you assigned on the `pd.read_csv` line?

Comment: Can you show an example of the `duplicates.csv` contents? The answers so far are making assumptions about what it contains.

Comment: As an aside, using `pandas` merely to read a csv into a list is like using a sledgehammer to sway a fly...

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil
dir1 = r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\TEMP2' # All the files are here
dir2 = r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\TEMP3' # Move to here IF it matches the `duplicates` list (aka: duplicates.cs
    
files = [i for i in os.listdir(dir1) if i.endswith(("csv", "txt")) and path.isfile(path.join(dir1, i))]
for f in files:
    shutil.move(path.join(dir1, f), dir2)
```

You can use this code snippet

---

you can change

```
duplicates_tuple = ("csv", "txt")
files = [i for i in os.listdir(dir1) if i.endswith(duplicates_tuple) and path.isfile(path.join(dir1, i))]
```

to

```
duplicates_tuple = tuple(pd.read_csv(r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\duplicates.csv', usecols=[1]).values.tolist()) 
files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i in (duplicates_tuple) and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
```

Comment: What about the `duplicates.csv` file that lists the files that should be moved?

Comment: you can change i.endswith(("csv", "text")) with tuple from .csv file that contains duplicate file extensions

duplicates_tuple = tuple(pd.read_csv(r'\\galaxy\WETS_ScanTest\duplicates.csv', usecols=[1]).values.tolist())

i.endswith(duplicates_tuple)

Comment: I'm not sure the file contains extensions, I thought it contains the names of the files that need to be moved.